# Get, modify, then print post title in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, ucfirst

Is there a way native way in wordpress to make uppercase the first letter of the first word of the scentence / [the_title](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) of the post?

If not, how do I do it in php, while it is wrapped in a `<a></a>` tag?

Here is the full line of code.

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php ucfirst(the_title());?></a>
```

As you see, I have tried [ucfirst](https://www.php.net/ucfirst), but it does not work. The other thing that I tried is:

```
<?php
$temp_title  = the_title();
$final_title = ucfirst($temp_title);
?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $final_title;?></a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ucfirst()` returns a string.  You need to `echo` the value returned from `ucfirst()`.

Furthermore, the WordPress function `the_title()` prints the title directly, rather than returning it as a string.  Use [`get_the_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title) instead.

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo ucfirst(get_the_title());?></a>
```

Comment: yes, the parenthesis i put in here is wrong (i will just make the correction) but it is not in my actual code. My code is exactly as your alternative but it does not work. and yes i used your main solution `<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo ucfirst(the_title());?></a>` but it does not work either. I appreciate your help anyways.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is your problem: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L51. As you can see `the_title()` is using `get_the_title()` and then `if($echo)` it echoes it out. I would experiment and try `get_the_title()`.

Answer (score -1):

First off you had an ending parantheses that didn't have a matching parantheses in your echo $final_title. Second you should try to apply ucfirst to the echo of your title. I removed $finaltitle, because it no longer serves a purpose. I haven't tried the code, but it should work. Please note that ucfirst() only works if the first letter is in the alphabet.

```
<?php
$temp_title  = the_title();
?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo ucfirst($temp_title);?></a>
```

Comment: i tried this earlier. This just returns the title as a simple string not in form of the url/link that i need. Wierd.

Comment: the_title(); should be changed with get_the_title();