# majuscle to the first character of the custom post title on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, ucfirst

I try to capitalize the first character of a custom post title on wordpress

I found this solution here:

[uppercase issue for title in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20853335/uppercase-issue-for-title-in-wordpress)

here is the code :

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo ucfirst(get_the_title());?></a>
```

it works well for normal content (post) on wordpress.

By cons, I can not use it on a costum post !

I tried also this :

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php ucfirst(the_title());?></a>
```

but its not working :-(

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to echo the output in the second example.

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo ucfirst(the_title('', '', false));?></a>
```

**Update:**

I just found in [the wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) that you should add a parameter to return the output. I have edited the code.

Comment: No error msg, title appears but first letter is not capitalized.

remark I use this code on an archive page the display in a loop the title of all custom post posted

Answer (score 0):

here is the code that i use :

```
 <?php 
                      // The Query
                      query_posts( array ( 'post_type' => 'question', 'posts_per_page' => 10 ) );
                      // The Loop
                     while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                        <li>
                            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo ucfirst(the_title('', '', false));?></a></h2>
                            <p class="questionexcerpt"> <?php the_excerpt(); ?> </p>

                        </li>

                      <?php endwhile; // Reset Query 
                      wp_reset_query();              
                      ?>
```